# Maximum 3 decimal places scores in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn in python, and cross_val_score() returns an accuracy with maximum 3 decimal places, how can i get the full value?
I get: 0.XXX, but i need: 0.XXXXXXXXX, this only happens with accuracy. Thank you.

```
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=50, random_state=42)

forest = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='log_loss', max_depth=7, max_features='log2', min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)

scores = cross_val_score(forest, X_phishing, y_phishing, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)

print(scores)
```

Probably a dataset issue, but can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Do you mean that 0.945343456 is rounded to 0.95 (you have a typo in your post), or are you actually getting 0.995, which is clearly wrong?

Comment: i'm getting 0.995, i want 0.945343456

Comment: i'm talking about the decimal places 0.XXXXXXX and not 0.XXX

Answer (score 1):

**I ran the same code with the iris dataset and it returned full value for accuracy**. The result that you got may be because of your dataset or some configuration. Please provide more information. I also provide a simple code that you can run to check the results.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

# Load Dataset
X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# Split Dataset to train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

# Fit data and evaluate by cross validation
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=50, random_state=42)
forest = RandomForestClassifier(criterion='log_loss', max_depth=7, max_features='log2', min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)
scores = cross_val_score(forest, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy')

# print scores
print(scores)
```

Comment: Yes i run your code and it works, i didn't set any configuration, what information can i give you to understand better? The dataset has 2000 samples and 130+ columns

Answer (score 1):

As `cross_val_score` returns a float, you can include the following line in your code, as it is only a print issue:

```
scores = cross_val_score(forest, X_phishing, y_phishing, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)

print(f'{scores:.8f}')
```

The documentation of `cross_val_score` cleary says that it will return a float, so if your first 5 numbers have these outputs, your decimal does not have any more digits then 0,995

Comment: no it doesn't seem a print issue, doing so i get: 0.99000000. The issue is that cross_val_score() returns a numpy array with values already rounded.

Comment: hwo you know that it is rounded and not the actual value?

Comment: because using RepeatedKFold i got 500 values and not one of them have more than three decimal places.

Comment: 0.99000000
0.98000000
0.96500000
0.98500000
0.98500000 first 5 scores

Comment: you dont have anymore digits then the one who have already shown without the print command

Comment: that's the point, why i don't have more digits? Are you telling me that all those values aren't rounded and they are like that?

Comment: yees, thats the output, please run the code with a different data and you will see more digits

Comment: yes i did it with the iris dataset and you are right, they were longer. It looked weird to me because of all those folds on a 2000 samples dataset and not even a 4 digits accuracy.